# SQL Вывести все столбы массивов где любой из массивов больше чем 1000

Tags: sql, postgresql

у меня есть база данных PostgreSQL где есть данные столбец в виде - phones[] (bigint) - массив

Как с помощью SQL запроса вывести любые массивы который больше чем 1000 допустим, при этом зная что столбик может быть пустой либо заполненый.?

Моя попытка была такой, но не увенчалась успехом.

```
select * from users where 1000 > ANY (phones);
```

Comment: А что такое "массив больше 1000" ? в нем есть элементы со значением больше 1000 или там более 1000 элементов или может сумма элементов больше 1000

Comment: @Mike там хранятся данные в виде {98,123} некоторые пустые {} нужно вывести все данные у которых один из елементов массива больше 1000

Comment: @Mike прошу прощения, не правильно выразился, не один из элементов, а любой из элементов.

Comment: тогда `1000 < ALL(phones)`

Comment: @Mike в таком случае выводятся все( даже пустые а тех которые < 1000 кажется даже и нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from users
 where 1000 < ALL (phones) and array_length(phones,1)>0;
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29d42/5)